# How can I make the clicking of an element submit a form?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Here's the code I have. I thought it was working but now I get a message saying submit() is not defined:

```
        <form action="/Account/LogOff"
              id="logoutForm"
              method="post"
              style="display: inline-block">
            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
            <a id="theme"
               onclick="submit(); return false;"
               title="Logoff">
                <i class="fa fa-power-off fa-fw"></i>
            </a>
        </form>
```

Note that is is an AngularJS form. Not sure that makes a difference as I am not needing any AngularJS functionality to do the submission.

Answer (score 2):

```
onclick="document.getElementById('logoutForm').submit(); retun false;"
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try this :

```
onclick="logoutForm.submit(); return false;"
```

Answer (score 0):

One more way to submit your form by adding name in form and then submit by below code.

I have added name="theform"  in form tag and then made changes on onclick

```
<form action="/Account/LogOff"
    id="logoutForm" name="theform"
    method="post"
    style="display: inline-block">
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <a id="theme"
        onclick="javascript:theform.submit(); return false;"
        title="Logoff">
        <i class="fa fa-power-off fa-fw"></i>sadadads
    </a>
</form>
```